# k-linkedness in graph theory on connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, intuition

What is k-linkedness in Graph theory ? It's available in Diestel but it's not very intuitive. Please explain.

Comment: I don't find the terminology from searching. How does Diestel define it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not paste an image here. Please have a look at the definition here:
http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/GrTh5_Ch3.pdf

Page number 74

Comment: @Uday You could copy the definition in text into your post. This is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Basically, *linked* means that for arbitrary pairs $(s_i,t_i),i=1,...,\ell$ of vertices in $X$ there are disjoint paths $P_i$ *outside* $X$ which connect these pairs.

At least this is how I understand the definition in the link.

---

**Analogy**

Place $\ell$ people at arbitrary points in $X$. Give any of them a target point in $X$ which they should reach. They have to leave $X$ and can only come back in their assigned target point. Then *linked* $X$ means that this is possible and that the the people can walk paths which not even cross each other. And this holds for arbitrary start and end vertices.